# Batch rename folders

Tags: directory, batch-processing, batch-rename

I have about 2000 folders all named like this

dataul_-_ppfsefs

music_-_ppfsefs

fun [gghhhses]

pictures_-_ppfsefs

backup [gghhhses]

tempfiles_-_ppfsefs

trash_it_-_ppfsefs

There are two unwanted portion at the end of the name "_-_ppfsefs" and " [gghhhses]", How to I rename them to look like this

dataul

music

fun

pictures

backup

tempfiles

trash_it

---

Edit: I'm on Mac OSX (installed brew, macports).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following two commands should do it:

```
for dir in * ; do mv "${dir}" "${dir/_-_ppfsefs/}" ; done

for dir in * ; do mv "${dir}" "${dir/ [gghhhses]/}" ; done
```

Comment: this works but when a folder doesn't "_-_ppfsefs" then it shows error; have Invalid argument.

Comment: found another issue if the folder has space then it doesn't work, can you help me to fix this. thanks

Comment: Unix like OSes (and I) don't like spaces :). Edited the answer to work with spaces. Note the double quotes.