# Rename folders with concatenation

Tags: windows, batch-file, rename

I would like to append the same string for all of the folders name (to the end) in the root folder.

Based on the below question these code may be useful:

```
for dir in * ; do mv "${dir}" "${dir/_-_ppfsefs/}" ; done
```

[Batch rename folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21475596/batch-rename-folders)

However, these code cuts the unwanted parts. And I want to add a string at the end of folder name.

Comment: You seem to confuse some other language with [tag:batch-file]; so what language are you using? the line of code you are posting is definitely not a [tag:batch-file]...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `mv "${dir}" "${dir}_-_ppfsefs"`, no slashes.